# error in config.status during 'make'

Tags: linux, makefile

I am trying to install a tool and when I do a make, I get error in config.status file as below:

```
 /bin/sh ./config.status
: command not foundne 6: 
: command not foundne 10: 
': not a valid identifier export: `SHELL
: command not foundne 16: 
./config.status: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
'/config.status: line 31: `     ;;
make[1]: *** [Makefile] Error 2
```

My first 35 lines of config.status is as below:

```
#! /bin/sh
# Generated by configure.
# Run this file to recreate the current configuration.
# Compiler output produced by configure, useful for debugging
# configure, is in config.log if it exists.

debug=false
ac_cs_recheck=false
ac_cs_silent=false

SHELL=${CONFIG_SHELL-bin/sh}
export SHELL
## -------------------- ##
## M4sh Initialization. ##
## -------------------- ##

# Be more Bourne compatible
DUALCASE=1; export DUALCASE # for MKS sh
if test -n "${ZSH_VERSION+set}" && (emulate sh) >/dev/null 2>&1; then :
  emulate sh
  NULLCMD=:
  # Pre-4.2 versions of Zsh do word splitting on ${1+"$@"}, which
  # is contrary to our usage.  Disable this feature.
  alias -g '${1+"$@"}'='"$@"'
  setopt NO_GLOB_SUBST
else
  case `(set -o) 2>/dev/null` in #(
  *posix*) :
    set -o posix ;; #(
  *) :
     ;;
esac
fi
```

Could anybody help me with this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think you downloaded your config file from a DOS (Windows) machine and have CRLF line endings.  The error message is trying to tell you about the line numbers, but the CR is confusing the output.  So, for example:

```
: command not foundne 6:
```

Is really something like:

```
./configure xxxx line 6: CR
: command not found
```

where the CR is the carriage return.

If you copied everything across without using text-mode FTP (or something else that translates CRLF line endings to newline (LF-only) endings), then it might be simplest to redo the transfer.  If you pulled it out of a `tar` file and it was in the wrong mode, then you will likely have to translate everything.  There are tools (`dos2unix` and `dtou` to name but two) that may be installed and may help with the DOS to Unix translation.

If it is just the Configure script, you can use `vim` to edit the file, and use:

```
:set fileformat=unix
```

to change the line endings, and then forcibly save the file

Comment: Found this in relation to another ./configure error. Based on your answer I just opened the configure file in Sublime Text and pressed Save. Problem solved. (well, now I have compile errors, but that's a different story)